# On AIX 6.1, batchman process does not correctly recognize the time zone of the local workstation in Workload Scheduler

Tags: aix, workload-scheduler

On AIX 6.1, the batchman process does not correctly recognize the time zone of the local machine that is set to GMT, even if, in the IBM Workload Scheduler CPU definition, it is correctly set to the correct timezone. You see the following message in the stdlist log :

```
"10:29:39 24.11.2015|BATCHMAN:AWSBHT126I Time in CPU TZ (America/Chicago): 2015/11/24 04:29 10:29:39
 
24.11.2015|BATCHMAN:AWSBHT127I Time in system TZ (America/Chicago): 2015/11/24 10:29 10:29:39

24.11.2015|BATCHMAN:+ 10:29:39 24.11.2015|BATCHMAN:+ AWSBHT128I
 Local time zone time differs from workstation time zone time by 360 minutes."
```

Batchman does not recognize the correct time zone because AIX 6.1 uses (International Components for Unicode) ICU libraries to manage the timezone of the system, and these ICU libraries are in conflict with the IBM Workload Scheduler libraries.

Comment: There are very few AIX readers on this forum. Http://ittoolbox.com has a forum for AIX that is active and helpful, but the best place to ask AIX questions is on the IBM support website ( I don't have the exact link, you'll have to search for it). Good luck.

Comment: AND this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://serverfault.com (prof. server-or-networking-S.E.-related infra. admin). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: Sounds like a bug report, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

i have an idea. You should export the TZ environment variable before starting IBM Workload Scheduler to the old POSIX format, for example, CST6CDT . This is an example of a POSIX name convention instead of an Olson name convention (for example America/Chicago). It avoids the new default TimeZone management through the ICU libraries in AIX 6.1, by switching to the old POSIX one (as in AIX 5.x).